# How to fix grunt permission problems?

Tags: magento-2.1, grunt

When trying to run grunt commands, I get the following error:

> Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home'
>       at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:665:18)
>       at Glob._readdir (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:662:20)
>       at Glob._process (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:446:15)
>       at Glob.iterator (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:181:10)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at new Glob (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:179:22)
>       at glob (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:57:11)
>       at Function.globSync [as sync] (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/glob/glob.js:76:10)
>       at /home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/lib/findup-sync.js:32:19
>       at Function.map (/home/pathto/magento/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/findup-sync/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:3509:27)

I've tried numerous fixes like running:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
```

And haven't been able to get it to work. I'm assuming this is a permission problem, but not really sure. I tried running grunt commands w/ sudo but it looks like the grunt command isn't in the path for sudo. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You only set permission for root of magento directory: `sudo chown -R 764 /home/pathto/magento` and `sudo chown -R 774 /home/pathto/magento/var` and set user or group for magento directory is apache user.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant chmod vs chown, but those permissions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can set recursive permission. For example to set 777 permission for var folder

```
[user@server ~$]sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/public_html/var
```